# how to bind the DDL in grid which is inside the Repeater?

Tags: asp.net

Am having a DDl in a grid again the grid inside the repeater. I need to bind the DDl in grid row data bound event. Am having issues in getting the index of the grid inside the Rowdatabound, Since it is inside the repeater.

```
protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (gvTest.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList drpBuild = (DropDownList) e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlBuild");
    }
}
```

Design :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptParent" OnItemDataBound="rptParent_OnItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
            <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFieldID23" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FieldID")%>'>
                    </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td class="tdGRD" colspan="2">
                    <div class="divScrollGrid">
                        <tw:twGridView ID="gvLabtestFeilds" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvLabtestFeilds_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30%">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFieldName" runat="server" Text="Test">
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblgvFieldName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FieldName") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBatchno" runat="server" Text="Batch Number">
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="ddlBatchNo" runat="server" CssClass="cbo">
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </tw:twGridView>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: could you possibly show the mark up also?

Comment: I Cant get you, Mark up means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList drpBuild = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("ddlBuild");
    }
}
```

P.S: I don't see any `ddlBuild` in your code.

Comment: am having problem with getting the index.. i haven't showed the ddl binding here. This is how am getting the grid index in rowdatabound but its throwing error


 "GridView gvTest = (GridView)rptParent.Items[0].FindControl("gvTest");"